# How to run Firebird gbak backup from Windows scheduler when no user is logged in

Tags: firebird, database-backups, windows-task-scheduler

On a Windows Server 2012 I have a script to backup our databases using service_mgr.

```
gbak -b -se localhost:service_mgr ....
```

It works very well, but we have to use it when no user are logged in the server. When we add a task in the Windows scheduler, it does not work. The script runs, but it seems GBak cannot do the backup.

Did anyone tried this with success? Is there any way?

Comment: Create a schedule task and check "Run whether user is logged or not" or simply use GBAK SCHEDULER( https://sites.google.com/site/gbakscheduler/home ) and put it to run as a service

Comment: Please include the exact definition of your scheduled task. As an aside, this is not really a programming question, and as such is probably more suitable for [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: `when no user are logged in the server` - sounds like a good place for UDF.  Do you have experience writing DLLs with plain C public API ? The last user logs off, Firebird calls the UDF function, which checks if GBAK is already running and spawns it if it does not.

Comment: Also, what exactly did you mean? Which server, which user? @mrapi seems to think you talk about Windows Desktop ( "interactive session" in Microsoft terms). I think it is database connection. And there can be whole lot of other interpretations.

Comment: @Arioch'The I think the OP means the task doesn't run when there is no user logged in into Windows itself, not when there is no user in the database.

Comment: Thank you to all of you, and very sorry if I was not so clear. In my case, I have to do one backup each day, regardless users are or not connected to the database; but gbak is not doing the hob if there is no Windows User logged in. The sintaxis is: gbak -b -se localhost:service_mgr e:\data\base.fdb e:\bak\data.fbk -user any -password one

Comment: then perhaps @mrapi was correct. However... a better approach would be, after backup complete, to restore that backup into a temporary file to check that backup itself was correct or not. Then delete that temp file and if any errors were - report them to system administrator. That simple tool probably does not that whole loop. See https://ib-aid.com/articles/firebird-gbak-backup-tips-and-tricks

Comment: there also seemed to be more complex utility, but seemd it did not generate profits and was cancelled (their site does no more exist) : https://download.cnet.com/xStarter-Job-Scheduler-for-Firebird-Interbase/3000-10254_4-75331393.html and then there was another tool, opensouce, https://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Servers/Database-Utils/FIBS-Firebird-Interbase-Backup-Scheduler.shtml  Them both were mentioned at https://firebirdfaq.org/faq141/ yet both seems to be gone for good and only left in 3rdparty sites.

Comment: I repeat my question: what is the exact definition of your task? I wasn't just talking about the command you used to create the backup, but the definition/configuration of the task itself. It is probably defined as _"Run only when user is logged on"_ instead of _"Run whether user is logged on or not"_ as mrapi already mentioned in the first comment.

Comment: No Mark. The taks is always running, I know that because the first step in the script is to delete old backup files, and it does that.